# Simpler way to replace/delete characters from string

Tags: string, object, replace, powershell-4.0

at first I had this piece of code that gets an object and shows a specific line. The line that I was getting was this one:

```
 @{      "id": "nic-1867724-4351584-0",=}
```

Now that I used -replace I am able to get just the part that I originally wanted:

```
 nic-1867724-4351584-0
```

This is the code that gives me clean line.

```
 $interfaceID = skytap vm show 4370436
 $interfaceID = Out-String | Select-Object ($stream -like "*nic-[0-9]*")[0]
 $right = $interfaceID -replace "....$"
 $interfaceID = $right -replace "@{.............",""
 Write-Host $interfaceID
```

Is there a better way to do that? Just in case there are more/less numbers on that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try with a regex, like capturing `nic*` to the next `"` :

```
$s='@{      "id": "nic-1867724-4351584-0",=}'
$nic=[regex]::match($s,'(nic-(.)*?)"').Groups[1].value
```

Answer (score 0):

1st option

```
$s='@{      "id": "nic-1867724-4351584-0",=}'
$s-replace'@|,='|ConvertFrom-Json
```

2nd option

```
$s='@{      "id": "nic-1867724-4351584-0",=}'
$s-replace'",=}'-replace'.+"'
```